# Groovy xmlparser get attribute value

Tags: groovy

I have a problem to parse an attribute value from following XML:

```
s='''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-ext
  xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-ext_1_0.xsd"
  version="1.0">
  <reload-interval value="3"/>
  <context-root uri="foo/bar" />
  <enable-directory-browsing value="false"/>
  <enable-file-serving value="true"/>
  <enable-reloading value="true"/>
  <enable-serving-servlets-by-class-name value="false" />
</web-ext>
'''

def contextroot
def xml = new XmlParser(false,false).parseText(s)
xml.each {
 if (it.name() == "context-root")
 contextroot = it.attributes().uri
}
```

It gives me the correct value. But is there a more direct approach? Something like

```
xml.name("context-root").uri
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to access this attribute directly you can do it with

```
xml.'context-root'[0].@uri
```

Comment: Or indeed `xml.'context-root'.@uri[0]` 

Comment: Now that's real groovy :-)  Tried several things,  but didn't find the right syntax.
Normally i use XmlSlurper, but got an exception, so i used XmlParser. But XmlSlurper(false,false).parseText() works also. Hmm, ok it was Friday ;-)
Thanks !

Comment: @tim_yates Thanks, used your proposal, feels more "natural".
There will be only one context-root node.